# Получение Integer из IntStream без преобразования в строку

Tags: java, java-stream

Как получить Integer из IntStream без преобразования в строку и обратно?
Чтобы в итоге получилось что `i` равно 12345

```
IntStream intStream = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Integer i = intStream. ??? // i = 12345
```

Comment: intStream.reduce((a, b) -> a * 10 + b).getAsInt();

Comment: @Serodv `getAsInt` в этой ситуации лишнее: метод `reduce` уже возвращает `int`

Answer (score 6):

Если в `IntStream` содержатся только цифры, то можно воспользоваться методом [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-), домножая уже полученное значение на 10 и добавляя текущую цифру:

```
IntStream intStream = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
int result = intStream.reduce(0, (a, b) -> 10 * a + b);
System.out.println(result);
```

Вывод:

> 12345